# Symfony2 Doctrine MySQL UTC_TIMESTAMP()

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to convert plain MySQL query to Doctrine query builder in Symfony2. 
I had a following part of SELECT query calculating different between the UTC timestamp in rcv.rtcdatetime field and current UTC:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, rcv.rtcdatetime, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) AS utcdiff
```

Apparently the UTC_TIMESTAMP() function is not available in Doctrine. I managed to find CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() function in Doctrine but I cannot find what value is supposed to be returned by that function. Is it the local server time or UTC timestamp? I tested it on several servers and still not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This library is able to extend Doctrine ORM with the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function: 
https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions

The calculation that the function does is however still executed on the mySQL Server:

The Mysql Server has serveral ways to configure the timezone internally used for all the operations. By default it should match your systems Timezone.

Read more about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out but it's not the TIMESTAMPDIFF function that I need it's the UTC_TIMESTAMP. I have an UTC timestamp field so I need to get the time difference in seconds between that field and now